# Software to find differences between server configurations

Tags: comparison, jakarta-ee, windows-server-2003

In order to troubleshoot a Java Web app that works in one server but not in a others, we are looking for software to find the software/registry/version differences between Windows 2003 servers. Does anyone knows of a free or commercial product that can help us do this?

Comment: What's the web container, and have you eliminated any chance of container configuration differences between the servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to testing the software/registry/version differences, would there be differences in your web app deployments?  You can use tools like WinMerge (free) or Beyond Compare (quite good but not free) to see if your deployments are different.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Also, it would be a good idea to compare JVM versions (what versions of the Java Runtime) are installed on the computers, as well as checking to see if the application server versions are different (Jboss, tomcat, websphere, etc...).